# For next loop in vba not executing all rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote a programm to replace special character in cell with normal character(alphabets)
I have written comments for each block in my programm.
However before executing all rows, after second row it goes to next column

```vb
Sub special_char_Replace()
    Dim h As String
    Dim m, clm, rw As Integer
    Dim colspc As New Collection
    Dim valspc As New Collection

    'Below part makes collection of special character and its replacement values

    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    m = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To m
        colspc.Add Cells(i, 1)
        valspc.Add Cells(i, 2)
    Next

    'Activate destination workbook from which special characters to be replaced

    Workbooks("common file.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    'Below loop replaces special characters and inserts original value at 5th 'column aside

    For clm = 5 To 6
        For rw = 2 To LR
            For i = 1 To m

                On Error Resume Next
                h = Range(Cells(rw, clm), Cells(rw, clm)).Find(What:=colspc(i), after:=Range(Cells(rw, clm), Cells(rw, clm)), LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlPart).Address
                If h <> "" Then
                    Range(h).Offset(0, 5) = Range(h).Value
                    Range(Cells(rw, clm), Cells(rw, clm)).Replace What:=colspc(i), replacement:=valspc(i), Lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
                End If
                h = ""
            Next i
        Next rw
    Next clm
End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is probably hiding errors from you.  Remove those, and see if that allows you to debug.

Comment: Also, if It's moving on to the next column after the 2nd row, can you confirm `LR` is > 3 when your code is running?

Comment: @VirendraUpadhye Did you remove **both instances** of `On Error Resume Next`? If so, did you try [stepping through](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code) the code? To make it easier to debug your code, you may break the "find" and "replace" lines into one expression per line. Side note: `Dim m, clm, rw As Integer` declares `m` and `clm` as `Variant`. Use  `Dim m As Integer, clm As Integer, rw As Integer` instead.

Comment: I have rechecked, it is showing error object variable or with block variable not set

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's support
I made changes, instead of find function, I have defined two dimentional string cellval(I,J)

First I will save all cell values in this string with for loop
cellval(I, j) = Cells(I, j).Value

After execution of replace command, below lines will check all string values with result

if there is changes it will relfect in output sheet

```
If cellval(I, j) <> Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(I, j).Value Then
```

Cells(I, j).Value = cellval(I, j)